# Better to install MySQL 32bit or 64bit on my 64bit Intel-based Mac (Perl/Python user)?

Tags: python, mysql, perl

I have had numerous headaches trying to get the MySQL APIs for Perl and Python working on my 64 bit Macbook Pro (Leopard).  I installed the 64 bit version of MySQL, but Googling around now I have the impression that this could be the source of my pain.  None of the various blogs and SO answers quite seem to work (for example [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395509/how-do-i-install-mysql-and-the-python-mysql-package-on-osx-leopard-or-how-do-i))

Could the 64 bit MySQL install be the culprit?  Can anyone confirm that they have MySQL access via Perl and/or Python on a 64 bit Mac using 64 bit MySQL?  Did you do anything special or face some similar problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

32-bit and 64-bit libraries don't play nice together. So, it depends whether you're using 32-bit Perl/Python or not.

If you are, you'll need 32-bit MySQL. Chances are your Python, at least, is 32-bit, since both the Apple-shipped Python and the binaries from python.org are 32-bit only.  You can build 64-bit Python (or- *gasp*- a 4-way i386/x86_64/ppc/ppc64 Universal Binary) from source, but unless you really need to work with absolutely huge disk files/amounts of memory (I'm talking multi-gigabyte memory maps, for example), chances are you do not need 64-bit anything right now.

Comment: thanks dwf... I will install the 32-bit MySQL and see how I go.  How do I tell whether my Perl/Python MySQL access libraries are 32 or 64-bit? I downloaded the Perl library using the cpan tool and Python was built from source (on my 64-bit machine)

Interesting comment on 64-bit MySQL.  Seems silly now, but when I installed the 64-bit version I guess my reflex was to choose the latest and greatest

Comment: ``file`` will usually tell you, if you hunt down the _mysql.so or whatever the filename is called. But if you didn't explicitly install/build 64-bit versions of Perl or Python then cpan and distutils will have built them 32-bit.

You may need to reinstall the mysql access libraries once you've got 32-bit MySQL installed, just to get the dynamic linkings right.

Answer (score 2):

You **will** need the 32vit vs 64bit of the MySQL *client libraries* to match the application you're trying to link them with. However, this not prevent you from connecting to a 64-bit install of MySQL *server*.

In Unix, the MySQL client libraries support multiple versions of themselves lying around; you just have to make sure the application is loading the correct one. This should be true to the Mac.

Comment: Good point, but I think most of the binary installers for MySQL on the Mac install one or the other.